# Android arabic Rihal textView

Tags: android, fonts, currency, arabic

I have to show this symbol in a TextView on android.

Symbol: ﷼

Result: [image]

I'm using other symbols of currencies in the code, but they are all displayed correctly.

Somebody can give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely correct, the result that you had is just a different writing for `﷼`.

The symbol `﷼` exists in Unicode while it is in reality a complete word of 4 letters, so some Arabic fonts give it a special writing compared to the separated word `ريال`. But it is indeed a correct writing, just more beautified.

Here is a preview of the symbol `﷼` and the word `ريال` using different fonts:

[image]

In Arabic manual writing art, letters and words could merge or be above each other. Fore example:

[image: Basmala]

Written in the last image a sentence of 4 words: `بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم`.